# Scanf leads to segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a text file:

```
In 0 John 66
In 1 May 77
In 0 Eliz 88
Out 0
Out 0
```

I'm trying to parse this text file using scanf, and at the moment send the values after "In" to the add function, however I'm getting a seg fault when trying to do this.

I have some code here:
A struct in a seperate header file:

```
typedef Officer test;

typedef struct {
    test tests[6];
    int s;
} copList;
```

And this one:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    int id;
} Officer;
```

Then I have my main method

```
int main(void) {
    FILE * ptr;
    char buffer [500];
    char * temp;
    int pos;
    int grade;
    char * name;
    copList * L;


    ptr = fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(ptr == NULL) 
        exit(1);


    temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    name = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    L = malloc(sizeof(copList));

    while(fgets(buffer,500,ptr) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buffer,"%s %d %s %d\n",temp,&pos,name,&grade);
        add(L->tests[pos],pos,L); //this gives me a seg fault
    }


    free(name);
    free(temp);
    free(L);
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

In a separate c file I have the add function.(Can't be changed)

```
void add(Test b, int pos, copList * L) {
//code to be added here later...
}
```

I've tried allocating different amounts of memory, but that didn't help. Also I noticed if I set a value to pos, in the while loop, before the add function call, I don't get a seg fault, but obviously that's not what I want, because the value wouldn't change. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `List` in `sizeof(List)`?

Comment: Edit, it's copList now, my bad. (Typo)

Comment: Is it also a typo there's no `void` in front of `add` defaulting to `int` return type?

Comment: BTW, why don't you copy & paste your code?

Comment: Changing it around makes it harder for other students to view my code, via a simple google search

Comment: It also makes it nearly impossible to answer your question, but I'm guessing that you aren't calling the `add` function correctly. In particular, I think `b` is supposed to be a structure that you've filled in.

Comment: The only way that line can segfault is if `L` is invalid (the malloc call failed), or if `pos` is out of range (which should not happen given the input you say you are using).  So the problem is actually somewhere else, probably within the `add` function.  Since you don't show the `add` function, its impossible to say, but I would suspect the issue is that is expecting some other definition of `Test` or `copList`

Comment: How would I go about calling the function correctly? Test b, is soposed to be the item I'm inserting into this list, I'm not sure how else I would call the add function. Could you show some example code?

Comment: It seems that if I change add(L->tests[pos],pos,L);, to add(L->tests[pos],0,L);, the code does not segfault, but obviously the position would always be the same. Is position someone not being initialized here?

Comment: while `copList` has List in the name, it is not a list.  In addition, your prototype for `add` has no way of doing anything useful, since it cannot modify `L` or the `Test` object as seen main, as they are passed by value.  But you say you can't change that, so what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Is `Test` supposed to be `test`?

Comment: No it's soposed to Test.

Comment: when calling the system function: `malloc()`,  the expression 'sizeof(char)' is defined as 1, so has no effect on the parameter passed to malloc().  All that expression does is clutter the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  The returned value from malloc() should always be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: these lines: ` if(ptr == NULL)  exit(1);` fail to let the user know what went wrong in the code execution:  suggest: `if( NULL == ptr ) { perror( "fopen for test.txt for read failed"); exit(1); }`  as that will output the message + the results from a call to strerror(), so the user will know exactly what went wrong.

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers, specifically '500'.  using 'magic' numbers makes code much harder to understand and a real headache to maintain.  Suggest: `#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN (500)`   Then use that meaningful name (MAX_BUFFER_LEN) throughout the code rather than the 'magic' number 500

Comment: if 'Test' is correct, then that type name is NOT defined anywhere in the posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I see with your code is that it does not check the return value of `sscanf` -- if sscanf returns something other than 2 or 4, that means your input is something other than what you say it is.  In addition, the arrays `temp` and `name` might overflow (on inputs other than what you show), which would cause undefined behavior.  Finally, the spaces and `\n` in the `sscanf` format are wrong and should be removed (though they shouldn't actually cause any problems in this case.)

So you code should be something like:

```
while(fgets(buffer,500,ptr) != NULL) {
    int count = sscanf(buffer,"%9s%d%9s%d",temp,&pos,name,&grade);
    if (count != 2 && count != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input line: %s", buffer);
        continue; }
    ... do stuff with temp and pos (only use name and grade if count == 4)
```

Comment: Indeed, if `sscanf()` fails to read values, `pos` will be uninitialised, but then used as an array index in `L->tests[pos]`.

Comment: So it seems that grade is always initalized but pos, isn't. (When attempting to set grade = pos (Which also leads to a segfault).

Comment: If grade was read successfully (count == 4), then pos must also have been read (count >= 2), as pos is before grade.

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
add(L->tests[pos],pos,L);
```

the first parameter is a copy of the 'test' struct.

It is almost always a bad idea to pass a whole struct.  Much better to just pass a pointer to the struct:

```
add( &(L->tests[pos]), pos, L );
```

Then, this line has a couple of problems:

```
void add(Test b, int pos, copList * L) {

1) 'Test' is a non-existent type, perhaps you meant: 'test'
2) 'b' is expecting a passed struct.  as mentioned above,
   it is (almost) always better to pass a pointer to a struct.
```